# how to add a message on the html page when the server is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to call the web page with the object . The web page running if the server is enabled . how to add the message that the server is off when the web page called by the `<object > < / object>`

example my script

```
<div class='konten'>
 <object  name="framesPage" width="100%" height="1000px" data="http://10.88.25.48:8765/vista-alignment/" type="text/html"></object> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<div class='konten' id='konten'>
 <object id='server' name="framesPage" width="100%" height="1000px" data="http://10.88.25.48:8765/vista-alignment/" type="text/html"></object> 
</div>
<script>
  var s = document.getElementById( 'server' );
  if ( s ) {
    s.addEventListener("error", function() {
      var k = document.getElementById( 'konten' );
      k.innerHTML = 'Server does not run';
    });
  }
</script>
```

More information about `onerror` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp).

Comment: @CnaoB, Nice its running,